# str_replace alternative for PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

In the `str_replace` [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for PHP it states the following:

> Because `str_replace()` replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements. See also the examples in this document.

Is there an equivalent function that does not have this gotcha or how can I safely do this?

Comment: What do you want to replace where? Can you give us an example?

Comment: Safely do *what*? Care to explain **particular task**, not your difficulties with solution?

Comment: Plan what you're replacing and pay attention to the order of replacement if you're replacing multiple string matches.  There's nothing inherently unsafe about the function if you plan properly.

Comment: You have this gotcha only if you pass an array of searcha/replace strings. Might be worth mentioning that if you know the order of replacements, a simple way to avoid potential gotchas is to start your "replacements" in reverse.

Comment: Re-order the replacements, so you don't have an overwrite.

Comment: strtr() may be an alternative depending on what you're replacing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking for [`strtr ( string $str , array $replace_pairs )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php).

> If given two arguments, the second should be an array in the form array('from' => 'to', ...). The return value is a string where all the occurrences of the array keys have been replaced by the corresponding values. The **longest keys** will be tried **first**. Once a substring has been replaced, its new value **will not** be searched again.

Example from the manual:

```
<?php
$trans = array("h" => "-", "hello" => "hi", "hi" => "hello");
echo strtr("hi all, I said hello", $trans);
?>
```

Will output:

> hello all, I said hi

Which should be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) im pretty sure you could make it replace all the values or one if thats what you're asking.

Or you could do it in pieces if theres an order to replace what you want

```
$value = preg_replace($pattern1, '..', $value);
$value = preg_replace($pattern2, '..', $value);
$value = preg_replace($pattern3, '..', $value);
```